# Make a single comma separated string from a range of numbers in R

Tags: r, string, range, substring, character

I'm trying to create a single comma separated string from a range of numbers, here 0 to 93, that would be "0,1,2,3,4...93".

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes. I knew about `paste0` but not about the `toString` variant so I learned something from this question and thus find it usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in single `paste`/`paste0`. It also removes the last comma directly.

```
range = 0:93
separator = ","
paste0(range, collapse = separator)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try

```
toString(0:93)
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, we can set our range and separator, and take advantage of the `substr` and `paste` functions:

```
range = 0:93
separator = ","
string_with_extra_comma = paste(paste0(range, separator),collapse = "")
```

This would be great but has an extra comma at the end. If we want to remove that we can use:

```
final_string = substr(string_with_extra_comma, 1,nchar(string_with_extra_comma)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(0:93, collapse = ",")
```